# Updating the apk created in the Coollaboratory Google Research

Tags: python, android, kivy, compatibility

I managed to create an apk (kivy/python) using [Coollaboratory](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/) and it works, but the Android device cannot install subsequent versions created in another session to the previous one, even if nothing changes in the code. APK versions are compatible only if created within the same session. How can I organize the apk update on the device?

I want compatible apk versions from kivy/python created in different Collaboratory sessions, but they are only compatible within the same session. I'm totally noob not only in android, but in whole programming, so sorry for silly question.

Comment: My guess is that the [android keystore](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode) is recreated each time you use a Collaboratory session, otherwise you'll have to delete the old APK version and install with the new APK version. Do note that building Android apps in Python is specialized area and doesn't have the free tutorials/resources that normal Java/Kotlin Android development has.

Comment: it seems to be true. Could you tell me if I will get version compatibility if I create an apk on my local PC using buildozer?

Comment: If you are creating with bulldozer on local PC that should keep the same android keystore, but different PC will have same limitation unless you copy keystore files.